# wso2 emm add new device operation

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I'm trying to add new device operation to wso2-emm.
I'm not sure what are the exact steps needed for adding new operation (I want to be able to have something like application list).
Although I'm not getting any error, i don't see the client gets the pull request.

Is there any tutorial how can I add new device operations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To which platform you need to add operations? Its not straight forward but should be able to add by adding some records in to the DB as well as the source code. Check the feature table in DB and handle the feature code properly in the source code.

Comment: thank you, i eventually found the problem and managed to make it work

Comment: @Sharas, could you post the steps you follow for adding new operation?

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I don't exactly remember the steps since it was quite long time ago. basically, as @Dilshan wrote, I just follow one of the operations and added a new recorded. i do remember it involve adding records to the database and to some files. Sorry i can't help more...

Comment: @Dilshan, what is the alphabetic(A,P and B) and number part of feature code related to?

Comment: @Sharas, did you remember what are the alphabetic(A,P and B) and number part of feature code related to?

Comment: There is no real relation and strict rules on defining codes. When designing we kept A as normal operations, P as policy etc. to identify and make it meaningful. However you can define your own feature code hence it should work.