# WSO2 EMM - Usage limitations

Tags: android, wso2, mdm

helpers and everyone,
First, I would like to thanks the site to give access at this source of information, has been really helpful in the past.
I'm newbie in this world of developing and MDM.
Today, I'm working on WSO2 EMM 2.0.1 solution. After a first setup, I have public and enterprise apps deployed on 2 Android devices, all in my LAN.
I work only with Android devices for the moment.
I plan to deploy this amazing program but I need some answers and technical advices about features and possibilities before going further.
Here they are :

- Because I need to limit usage of my devices, I need to restrict use of native apps on each devices such as Internet browser or play store and I would like to allow ONLY installation from my app store. So, does there is a way to restrict actions or anything else ?
- Does blacklist feature is still available in this version of wso2 emm ?
- For a security topic, I would like to know in which circonstances, I can filter URL from a web browser to disable access on specific sites. Do I have to pass through a proxy in my network ? or it exist another way to do that when devices are connected on public network ?
- And for a question of mobility, how can I setup my devices and my LAN for my devices to communicates with my server and access to my apps store or others data when devices are outside my office ?
- And my last question, since a user can remove the agent himself, is there a way to prevent this ?

I'm really stuck on this points.
Thanks you in advance for your help and your light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Find the feedback for your problems in order given below,

- EMM 2.0.1 dose not support restrict use of native apps and alown app installation only from a given  app store.

> Restricting application installation only for a provided app store
>   will e enabled in EMM 2.1.0.

- Application blacklist feature is not available in EMM 2.0.1

> Application blacklisting and white listing will be available in EMM
>   2.1.0

- You don't have the ability of filter URL from a web browser in EMM 2.0.1.you need to utilize a proxy service for this.
- In order to device to communicate with the EMM even out side of the office you need to host EMM sever in a public domain and connect devices.
- Yes this is possible in EMM 2.0.1 but this is solved in EMM 2.1.0

---

> Note that EMM 2.1.0 is the upcoming release

---

Comment: Hi Kachiecx,Thanks you very much for your answers, it really help.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But I can't wait for the EMM 2.1.0 release. Can you just guide me on how WSO2 are planning to implement it? I am just looking for iOS restriction. I discovered that we can add device operations by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691067/wso2-emm-add-new-device-operation. Is that the correct way to add app restrictions?

Comment: Yes you can do that. WSO2 EMM supports new feature implementations.
You can follow this and create your self another feature or many. http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2014/03/how-to-write-a-wso2-carbon-component/